# Python: how to make HTTP request internally/localhost

Tags: php, python, http

I want to send some parameters from a python script on my server to a php script on my server using HTTP. Suggestions?

Comment: urlopen/urlopen2 can build send GET and POST queries, but you need to elaborate what you want to do

Comment: Okay: I want to make a GET query from a python script to a php script being served by apache2. Both scripts reside on the same machine/same ip address.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy using [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html):

```
import urllib

myurl = 'http://localhost/script.php?var1=foo&var2=bar'

# GET is the default action
response = urllib.urlopen(myurl)  

# Output from the GET assuming response code was 200
data = response.read()
```

Comment: Cheers! Given that the same thing could, in a sense, be achieved using stdin or argument passing, what is the relative overhead?

Comment: I have no idea, but since you're using Python you can make the script accept use dynamic variables and don't need to resort to system (cli) calls for it.